# Element's style's top and left sometimes doesn't update in ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this element that looks something like this:

```
render() {
    // figure these values out based on props and state
    let left = ... 
    let top = ...
    // the values of these are floating point or integer

    let src = '/image.png'
    let style={top: top, left: left}
    console.log("SETTING STYLE", style)
    return <img src={src} style={style}/>
}
```

So far so good. A stylesheet sets these images to `position:absolute` and that works. I can control the position of the elements with props and state and business logic.

However, the element can be dragged and moved around (using [Draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/)). I have an event listener that listens to when the element stopped being dragged around. That gives me a position (x, y). I then pass that into a function which, based on some business logic, "corrects" the numbers and updates the props and state so that the element is re-rendered.

However, **sometimes**, the change **doesn't take effect**. Why?!

As you can see I `console.log` what the `style` should be and I can clearly see that it says something like `Object {top: 123.5, left: 234.5}` but when I inspect the element in my devtools and look at the Rules set, the numbers are different! 
E.g. [image: from Inspector devtools]

Basically, those numbers sometimes don't add up with what I set when I rendered the element in the `render()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer the Draggabilly plugin sets the `top` and `left` too **after** it has fired the event which my React app is relying on. I.e. It does something like this:

```
Draggabilly.prototype._stopDragging = function(event) {
    var x = event.something.x; y = event.something.y;
    this.triggerEvent('dragEnd', ...)
    this.element.style.left = x
    this.element.style.top = y
}
```

So two distinct systems are trying to set the style attribute.